# Crystal Report Not loading

Tags: vb.net, deployment, crystal-reports

I hav  visual studio 2008  project and in client computer in crystal report there occurs error and the message is "CrystalDescision.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0,Culture=neutral..."
so how can i load cyrstal report without installing visual studio 2008...

Answer (score 1):

In the deployment project right click on the project in solution explorer and got to properties. Add Crystal as a prerequisite here and it will install crystal dlls from the web or from the deployment package as required!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to the give them the crystal report dll's

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue in our project and the solution was to have the client install Crystal reports on his PC.

You will need to install only the Basic Runtime version of CrystalReports which you can get from [here](http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/additional_downloads/runtime.asp) (this corresponds to the 10.5 version).

Regarding deployment you have 2 options:

- Make CrystalReports a prerequisite - for example if you have an installer for your application you can mark CrystalReports as a prerequisite and every time the setup will be ran, a check will be made for CrystalReports and if not found it will be downloaded automatically (this behavior is configurable)
- Provide CrystalReports setup with you own application - you will have to include the "[merge modules](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxi/en/en/RDC_SDK/rdc_com_deployment_doc/doc/rdcsdk_com_deployment_dg/RDC_Deployment4.html)" from CrystalReports (.msm) in your setup